# - FirebaseError Expect manifest yaml to specify a version number when deploying functions only

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Have a basic firebase project setup by doing firebase init.
Changed or altered no settings.

When trying to deploy I get the following error:

```
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
Error: Failed to parse build specification:
 - FirebaseError Expect manifest yaml to specify a version number
```

If I deploy hosting and firestore separately by
`firebase deploy --only hosting` all works fine with these.

Googling gave me no useful information regarding the error message.
Anyone have any idea on what is causing this and could point me in some direction to solve it?

Comment: In my case it was a missing import at the top of the main.py

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the reason for this error (abosutely irrelevant to the message) was a lazy invocation (that is outside of the handler) of `functions.config()` on some environment variable that was not presented anymore. No matter how safe the actual call was made to ensure exactly this case is handled, it caused firebase CLI to choke on deployment with this rather cryptic message. I guess it's related to the mechanism finding all functions declarations in the source code. Nevertheless, could have been done better by firebase devs.

Had to inspect everything with `firebase functions:config:get`, drop everything unused, and create anything needed. An unfortunate waste of a few hours as there's no way one could extract it by the message in the Firebase source code on GitHub.